# Material UI React v5.8.0 "disableRipple: true" does not disable button ripple. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to disable the ripple on buttons in Material UI v5 because my product does not need it. According to [the Material UI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-disable-the-ripple-effect-globally), all I have to do is this:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component ⚛️
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The props to apply
        disableRipple: true, // No more ripple, on the whole application !
      },
    },
  },
});
```

So I do that to my own theme, which is here:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableRipple: true,
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textTransform: 'none',
          borderRadius: "40px",
          fontSize: "1.1875rem"
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

The style overrides work fine. But the disableRipple does not work. It still ripples. I tried applying to the default props of MuiButton as well. No luck.

I am using typescript, but this is not returning any errors.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, you can use this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-no-ripple-theme-z7m4u9?file=/demo.tsx) for reference.

Comment: @tromgy My project is still showing the ripple. I've quit the project, restarted, etc....it's still rippling.

I'm also using Next JS....is that the culprit?

Comment: You can try deleting the **.next** folder. Next is notorious for caching.